# Object's method can be called in function when function is called on its own, but when function called via setTimeout the object is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, es6-class

I have the following class `Conference`:

```
//UrlSerializer is for encoding JSON objects into GET url
const UrlSerializer=require('./urlSerializer');

class Conference{

    constructor(client,workspace){
        this.client=client;
        this.workspace=workspace;
        this.urlSerializer=new UrlSerializer();
    }


    announce(conferenceSid,timeRemaining){
        var parameters={
            timeRemaining:timeRemaining
        }
        var url=this.urlSerializer.serialize('conferenceAnnounceTime',parameters);
        console.log("conference.announce url: "+url);
        this.client.conferences(conferenceSid)
            .update({
                announceUrl:url,
                announceMethod:'GET'
            })
            .then(conference=>console.log(conference.friendlyName));
    }

    setTimedAnnounce(initialMinutes,minutesToElapse,conferenceSid){
        var minutesRemaining=initialMinutes-minutesToElapse;
        setTimeout(this.announce,minutesToElapse*60000,minutesRemaining);
    }

}

module.exports=Conference;
```

`UrlSerializer` is:

```
const querystring=require('querystring');
require('env2')('.env');

class UrlSerializer{

    constructor(){
        this.paramArrayName="parameters";
    }

    serialize(endpoint,paramArray){
        var url=process.env.APP_BASE_URL+"/"+endpoint;
        console.log("urlSerializer base url: "+url);
        var arrayString=JSON.stringify(paramArray);
        console.log("urlSerializer stringified parameter array: "+arrayString);
        var fullUrl=url+"?"+querystring.stringify({[this.paramArrayName]:arrayString});
        console.log("urlSerializer full url: "+fullUrl);
        return fullUrl;
    }   
}

module.exports=UrlSerializer;
```

I call `conference` functions from an Express endpoint in a different module `server`, as follows:

```
app.get('/conferenceEvents',function(req,res){
    conferenceSid=req.query.ConferenceSid;
    conference.announce(conferenceSid,initialMinutes);
    conference.setTimedAnnounce(initialMinutes,0.25,conferenceSid);
    res.type('application/json');
    res.status(200).send();
});
```

The call to `conference.announce` succeeds with console output:

```
urlSerializer base url: http://x.ngrok.io/conferenceAnnounceTime
urlSerializer stringified parameter array: {"timeRemaining":5}
urlSerializer full url: http://x.ngrok.io/conferenceAnnounceTime?parameters=%7B%22timeRemaining%22%3A5%7D
conference.announce url: http://x.ngrok.io/conferenceAnnounceTime?parameters=%7B%22timeRemaining%22%3A5%7D
```

But when 15 seconds elapses after calling `conference.setTimedAnnounce()`, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'serialize' of undefined
    at Timeout.announce [as _onTimeout] (c:\thisAppPath\conference.js:45:30)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:502:15)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
```

I'm thinking maybe when the timer calls `announce`, it's doing it in a way that the `urlSerializer` instance is out of scope.  How do I make it recognize `urlSerializer` when `announce` is called via `setTimeout()`?

EDIT: I tried saving the `this` scope as follows:

```
    setTimedAnnounce(initialMinutes,minutesToElapse,conferenceSid){
        var that=this;
        var minutesRemaining=initialMinutes-minutesToElapse;
        setTimeout(that.announce,minutesToElapse*60000,minutesRemaining);
    }
```

but that just gave me the same error.

EDIT 2:

I used Barmar's `this.announce.bind(this)` solution and that resolved the `TypeError`, but the parameter array and URL are not being properly constructed in the setTimeout() call of announce; console output as follows:

```
urlSerializer base url: http://x.ngrok.io/conferenceAnnounceTime
urlSerializer stringified parameter array: {}
urlSerializer full url: http://x.ngrok.io/conferenceAnnounceTime?parameters=%7B%7D
conference.announce url: http://x.ngrok.io/conferenceAnnounceTime?parameters=%7B%7D
```

I suspect that there's somewhere else that I need to use `.bind(this)` so that `urlSerializer.serialize()` will get called with `this` in the proper scope, but I haven't tracked it down yet.

EDIT 3:

Never mind, I figured it out--`setTimeout` needed to have `conferenceSid` passed in as an argument as well as `minutesRemaining`.  Working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    setTimeout(this.announce,minutesToElapse*60000,minutesRemaining);
```

needs to be

```
    setTimeout(this.announce.bind(this),minutesToElapse*60000,minutesRemaining);
```

Passing a function property as an argument doesn't bind the `this` context. It's only bound automatically when you call the method with that syntax.

Comment: There are dozens of dups of this question/answer.

Comment: That resolved the TypeError, but I'm still having `this` context issues, see Edit 2 that I just added to my OP.